# Push notification support in Twilio IOS sdk

Tags: objective-c, twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to get push notifications on an app that's using Twilio IP Messaging. After following the instructions on twilio guides.

The AppDelegate functions to register for remote notifications is working well - the iOS devices successfully provides the device token to the Twilio Client. However, the TwilioIPMessagingClient gives no indication of success or failure while registering the token.I have used delegates also for that Moreover, I don't get any sign of push notifications when messages get sent.

I have checked logs also where I can see the correct logs:

```
TNNotificationClient | Starting registration..., id: <....>
TNRegTransport | Creating registration: apn - <....>
TNRegTransport | Registration is created, location: https://ers.us1.twilio.com/v1/registrations/<...>
```

Where exactly I'm missing? One hint I got to know after much research that in server PHP app, I need to enable push on IPMesaging services client becuase its disabled by default. If yes, where exactly or in which .php file I have to enable it?

Reference:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notification-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Someone else recently solved this problem realizing that they had not set the [`New Message` notification type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notification-configuration#push-types) to be explicitly enabled as follows from the PHP example:

```
// Update the service webhooks
$service = $client->services->get("YOUR_IP_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID");
$response = $service->update(array(
    "Notifications.NewMessage.Enabled" => "true",
    "Notifications.NewMessage.Template" => "A New message in ${CHANNEL} from ${USER}: ${MESSAGE}",
));
?>
```

Would this solve it for you?